# What are the occupations of a person born as a Vaisya?

Tags: scripture, vaishya

What are the suitable (prescribed) occupations of a person born as a Vaisya?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Occupations prescribed for a Vaishya person are mentioned in the following verse from Parashara Smriti's 1st chapter:

> 63. To invest money on interest, to be a jeweller, to tend cattle, tillage and trade, — these are declared as occupations for the Vaisya
>     caste,

Comment: Some texts ascribe the profession of agriculture to Shudras too. What's your viewpoint in this matter ?

Comment: Shudras are always allowed to do agriculture. According to Parashara Smriti, not only Shudras even Brahmins are allowed to depend on agriculture @AnubrataBit